# What's the meaning of "conv" in the function name "localeconv()"?

Tags: c, localization, locale

What's the meaning of "`conv`" in the function name `localeconv()` in header `<locale.h>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The HP-UX manual pages](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02259853/c02259853.pdf), summarize the purpose of `localeconv()` as:

> localeconv() - query the numeric formatting conventions of the current locale

The [IBM z/VM C library manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v610.edclv/locale.htm) describes it similarly:

> localeconv() — Query Numeric Conventions

I'm not sure exactly where the origin of this wording was, but a number of sources do appear to agree that it stands for "conventions".

Answer (score 1):

I believe (but am not 100% positive) that it stands for "conventions," as in the conventions of the current locale you are in for expressing money, numbers, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think I can agree with you, but if there is a webpage explains the origins of the name? Are there any other functions with the name of "*conv"?

Comment: @UniMouS- I just read the C ISO spec and there is no elaboration there.  I was hoping to get a definitive reference that way. :-)